# sum within (date)

Tags: r, sum, radix

I'm trying to calculate the sum of values (in `XYZmin`) that occur on the same date.

My data looks like this,

```
bar <- structure(list(date = structure(c(15622, 15622, 15622, 15628, 
15632, 15635, 15639, 15639, 15639, 15639, 15639, 15642, 15646, 
15646, 15650, 15650, 15650, 15657, 15660, 15660, 15674, 15681, 
15691, 15695, 15709, 15716, 15723, 15730, 15737, 15737, 15737, 
15737, 15737, 15737, 15740, 15743, 15743, 15743, 15744, 15744, 
15744, 15744, 15746, 15751, 15755, 15758), class = "Date"), XYZmin = c(-20, 
-15, -10, -70, -60, -60, -95, -10, -10, -40, -25, -25, -20, -10, 
-3, -5, -25, -5, -70, -5, -30, -30, -25, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 
-10, -10, -30, -30, -10, -10, -10, -60, -30, -10, 75, -10, -10, 
-10, 60, 60, -15, 60)), .Names = c("date", "XYZmin"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-46L))

head(bar)   
        date XYZmin
1 2012-10-09    -20
2 2012-10-09    -15
3 2012-10-09    -10
4 2012-10-15    -70
5 2012-10-19    -60
6 2012-10-22    -60
```

What I'm struggling to accomplish is to create a new variables `XYZtot` where, within datas that occur more then once, and sum the 1st and 2nd value at the 2nd data, and sum the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd value at the 3rd data. Here is a snipped of what I am aiming at.

```
head(new_bar_with_XYZtot) 

        date XYZmin XYZtot
1 2012-10-09    -20    -20
2 2012-10-09    -15    -35
3 2012-10-09    -10    -40
4 2012-10-15    -70    -70
5 2012-10-19    -60    -60
6 2012-10-22    -60    -60
```

#### updated with the *big* `microbenchmark` test

```
alexwhan <- function(bar,date,XYZmin) ddply(bar, .(date), transform, XYZmin.sum = cumsum(XYZmin))

Arun <- function(bar,date,XYZmin) within(bar, {XYZtot <- ave( XYZmin, date, FUN=cumsum)})

agstudy <- function(bar,date,XYZmin) transform(bar, XYZtot = ave(XYZmin, date, FUN = cumsum))

# install.packages("data.table", dependencies = TRUE)
library(data.table)
mnel <- function(bar,date,XYZmin)  bar <- data.table(bar); bar[, XYZmin.sum := cumsum(XYZmin), by = date]

# install.packages("microbenchmark", dependencies = TRUE)
require(microbenchmark)

# run test
res <- microbenchmark(alexwhan(bar,date,XYZmin), Arun(bar,date,XYZmin), agstudy(bar,date,XYZmin), mnel(bar,date,XYZmin), times = 666)


## Print results:
print(res)
```

the numbers,

```
Unit: microseconds
                        expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
 alexwhan(bar, date, XYZmin) 14484.077 15056.613 15237.760 15945.482 72650.126   666
     Arun(bar, date, XYZmin)   963.632  1018.311  1070.759  1138.655  4988.226   666
  agstudy(bar, date, XYZmin)  1967.292  2021.115  2078.261  2158.689  9240.500   666
     mnel(bar, date, XYZmin)   251.312   270.295   282.821   325.040  6540.367   666


### Plot results:
boxplot(res)
```

[image: Plot results]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ave`   also but with `transform`

```
transform(bar, XYZtot = ave(XYZmin, date, FUN = cumsum))
```

**EDIT** after the OP comment

```
transform(bar, XYZtot = ave(XYZmin, date, FUN = 
                          function(x)
                            if(length(x) < 1) NA 
                            else c(cumsum(x[-length(x)]),NA)))
```

Comment: Removed the `$` sign before `date`.

Comment: I ended up using this solution, also it came out quite good in the microbenchmark test (see above).

Comment: Is there an easy way to set all the values that are summed into a total `NA`, but not the total? For the first date (2012-10-09) that would entail recoding `-20` and `-35` in `NA`'s'.

Answer (score 5):

If you are going for speend, I'll put in a `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
bar <- data.table(bar)

# assigning within bar
bar[, XYZmin.sum := cumsum(XYZmin), by = date]
```

This will scale for large data!

Comment: Impressive. I added your solution to the _big_ `microbenchmark` test. Thank you for responding.

Comment: Is there an easy way to set all the values that are summed into a total `NA`, but not the total? For the first date (2012-10-09) that would entail recoding `-20` and `-35` in `NA`'s'. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one using `ave`:

```
bar <- within(bar, {XYZtot <- ave( XYZmin, date, FUN=cumsum)})
```

Comment: Even more concise, thanks! I like how you make use of `within`!

Comment: All thanks to @AnandaMahto! The lord of `ave`, `within` and `reshape` :)

Comment: Is there an easy way to set all the values that are summed into a total `NA`, but not the total? For the first date (2012-10-09) that would entail recoding `-20` and `-35` in `NA`'s'.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

```
bar.sum <- ddply(bar, .(date), transform,
                 XYZmin.sum = cumsum(XYZmin))
bar.sum
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This i exactly what I was looking for, I'll accept it ASAP. Thanks!